# Regex for rule "cannot have this character before and after"

Tags: regex

#### Question

I'm trying to match PowerShell dash comments (`# ...`) but not inline comments (`<# .. #>`) in same regex. How can I achieve it?

#### Goal

##### Match

I'd like to match PowerShell comments (using hashtag comment syntax). So simply everything after `#` is commented out. I use `#(.*$)/gm` for it.

Test-cases where the regex match is written inside brackets `[..]`:

- `Write-Host "Hello world" [# comment here]`
- `[# A line with only comment]`
- `Comment without whitespace[#before]`
- `[Comment with whitespace [#after ]`

##### Do not match

However what I'd like to use here is have an exception for "inline comments syntax". Inline comments in PowerShell looks like `lorem <# inline comment #> ipsus`.

So here I'm looking for exclusions for:

- `Write-Host "Hello world" <# inline comment here #>`
- `<# A line with only inline comment #>`
- `Comment without whitespace<#no whitespace#>around`
- `Inline comment <# in middle #> of line`
- `Comment with whitespace #comment with >`
- `Comment with whitespace #comment with <`
- `Comment with whitespace #comment with <# test #>`

#### What I tried

I tried to use `[^<>]` for something like `#[^<>](.*[^<>]$)` but it did not work for all cases given in the above.

[My progress on regex101 until I got stuck](https://regex101.com/r/GlEPzO/1/).

#### Why

I'm parsing PowerShell in JavaScript/TypeScript runtime to be able to inline them to run them in batch (`cmd`) for a community driven [open-source project](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy). I know there will be exceptions to this (like strings with dashes inside) but I trade off simple regex parsing for robustness.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking for `<` before a `#` char and convert all negated character classes into negative lookarounds to avoid crossing over line boundaries:

```js
#(?<!<#)(?![<>])(.*)$(?<![<>])
// Or, to also check for #> after <# use
#(?<!<#(?=.*#>))(?![<>])(.*)$(?<![<>])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlEPzO/2).  Remove `(?<![<>])` negative lookbehind if you do not want to fail the match if the line ends with `<` or `>`.

*Details*:

- `#` - a `#` char
- `(?<!<#)` - no `<#` allowed immediately to the left of the current location (note this check is only triggered after `#`, so that the regex engine could check only the positions after `#`, not every position in the string (`(?<!<#(?=.*#>))` lookbehind with a nested lookahead makes sure the `#` matched is not the second char of a `<#...#>` substring)
- `(?![<>])` - immediately on the right, there must be no `<` and `>`
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string
- `(?<![<>])` - at the end of string, there must be no `<` and `>` chars.

Comment: I just realized that it fails when using single `<` or `>` in a dash comment. E.g. `Comment with whitespace #comment with >`, `Comment with whitespace #comment with <`, `# Comment with <# test #>`. Would be possible to match those as well?

Comment: @U.Bulle do you mean if they *end with* `<` or `>`, they must be matched? Then remove the last lookbehind. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlEPzO/3). Also, if you need to also check for `#>` after `<#`, you may use `#(?<!<#(?=.*#>))(?![<>])(.*)$`